# Github two repositories (each with a deploy key) depend on a third, how to authorize them?

Tags: github, ssh

I'm switching from Bitbucket to Github.

I have tree repository under my git organization account:

- **repo A** with a custom deploy key (read-only)
- **repo B** with a custom deploy key (read-only)
- **dependency 1** (without any key ATM)

Note that **repo A** and **repo B** are separate and run under different user account, each with its own SSH key pair.

Both repo A and repoB depends on dependency 1 (using composer.json and an SSH url). On bitbucket, I would add both keys (**repo A** and **repo B**) the repository for **dependency 1**.

It doesn't work on Github because [I can't add the same key two times](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys).

Any idea apart from returning to Bitbucket?

As suggested, **the following isn't working** (id_rsa is for Repo A, dependency_id_rsa is for the dependency):

```
Host github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dependency_id_rsa
```

Comment: Where are you using the deploy keys? In a CI / build tool?

Comment: Deploying the website itself on the server, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> dependency 1 (without any key ATM)

Ideally, dependency1 repository itself should have its own deploy key which would grant access to it.
As described in [`composer/composer` issue 2074](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2074#issuecomment-335880273), that would allow to access that dependency, through a configured `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: I can generate a deploy key for dependency 1, then repo A can configured with two identity `IdentityFile` lines?

Comment: @gremo That is the idea, yes.

Comment: Can't make it work, i can't clone the dependency with the following configuration as you suggested: ```
Host github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dependency_id_rsa
```

Comment: @gremo What OS are you using, with which version of Git?

Comment: git version 1.8.3.1 under Centos 7, I've updated the question with the full example that you proposed

Comment: 1.8 is a bit old, any chance you can upgrade it? (or request to be upgraded)? (I work with CentOS 7.8 at work myself)

Comment: You think that that will solve the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231023/discussion-between-vonc-and-gremo).